# C# source interpreted from C#

Tags: c#

I can execute a C# source from PowerShell and a PowerShell source from C#.
The question is, How can I execute a C# source from a C# program without compiling with csc.exe?

Comment: Don't. Just don't. You're probably thinking about an eval() function, like with javascript and other dynamic languages. The thing is, for general purpose languages, eval() is a huge gaping security issue. C# does make it possible to execute c# source code, but it rightly makes it very hard to do.

Comment: Read up on Roslyn.  It's a new 'compiler-as-a-service' capability in the .NET platform.  https://roslyn.codeplex.com/ -- Ultimately, you cannot really execute C# code without compiling, but you can use Rosyln to do some "scripty" stuff with C#

Comment: Since C# has open specification you can write your own compiler :)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is explicitly catered for in the .net framework using the CodeDom class namespace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx(v=vs.110).aspx System.CodeDom and System.CodeDom.Compiler.

(from the documention)

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

// Build the parameters for source compilation.
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

// Add an assembly reference.
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add( "System.dll" );

// Generate an executable instead of 
// a class library.
cp.GenerateExecutable = true;

// Set the assembly file name to generate.
cp.OutputAssembly = exeFile;

// Save the assembly as a physical file.
cp.GenerateInMemory = false;

// Invoke compilation.
CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, sourceFile);
```

I realise this does use the compiler internally, which is something the OP wished to avoid, but I can't see any reason not to use this to .